# Mac OSX 10.11.1 can't negotiate TLS1.2 cipher suite with IIS 8.5

Tags: certificate

I am diagnosing a Mac running OSX 10.11.1 which cannot connect with an Exchange 2013 server (on Win 2012R2 w/IIS 8.5).  I enabled TLS 1.1 and 1.2 via registry keys on the Exchange server, but when the client tries to connect I see events 36874 and 36888 on the server with text:

```
An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request has failed.
```

How can I ensure the Mac and the Win server negotiate a mutually acceptable cipher suite?  (I'm not even sure what a cipher suite is).  In case it matters, the server's cert is signed with SHA512 and it uses a self generated root CA cert also with SHA512.

I found this article which suggests TLS1.2 doesn't support SHA512:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/silvana/archive/2014/03/14/schannel-errors-on-scom-agent.aspx

Does this mean I have to regenerate my ROOT certificate (which is signed with SHA512), or just the exchange server's cert (which is also signed with SHA512)?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else - I confirmed that its ok for the root cert to be signed with SHA512, just not the server cert.  Mac OS X (10.11.x) will NOT understand/work with it.  If you regenerate a cert using SHA384 then the Mac is happy

Comment: So, it sounds like your server cert used SHA512, so your Mac tried to use it as part of its cipher suite (because why ask for lesser encryption than what the server seems capable of, right?), but it turns out that unpatched Windows Server doesn't actually have SHA512 enabled as part of a TLS 1.2, so IIS balked. Apparently you can install a patch on IIS to make it support SHA512 properly: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2973337

Comment: The MS patch looks to be 1 year old - shouldn't this already be installed automatically if the Windows server is fully up to date?